# lambda cannot access to s3 bucket restricted by cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a s3 bucket as origin of a cloudfront. The bucket have all public access blocked. I create a lambda function that download, process and upload s3 object. I create a role for the lambda and add a non public policy, according the meaning of public for amazon resources.. Here is the policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3LambdaAccessObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXXXX-dev-videos-origin/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:function:YYYYYYYYYYYY_conversor"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3LambdaListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXXXX-dev-videos-origin",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:function:YYYYYYYYYYY_conversor"
                }
            }
        }
```

However, i get access denied code when trying to download and upload a file to the s3 via sdk.
I even has added the lamnda to the s3 policies but still no result:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "aws_iam_policy_document_origin",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3GetObjectForCloudFront",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXX-origin/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3ListBucketForCloudFront",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXX-origin"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3PutObjectForCloudFront",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXX-origin/private/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3LambdaAccessObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXX-origin/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:YYYYYYYYYYY:function:XXXXXXXXXXX"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3LambdaListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXX-origin",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:YYYYYYYYYYY:function:XXXXXXXXXXX"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
    ]
}
```

The lambda work just fine if the public access blocking is removed. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code that I was testing try to upload a file with public ACL policy, what is denied by the s3, having all the public access blocked. The blocking also prevent any account or service to update this non public policy for the bucket or object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html

Answer (score 5):

The whitelist for the Lambda function Arn will not work as the Lambda function connects using its Lambda role to perform any of these interactions.

Instead you will need to [whitelist the IAM role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) that your Lambda has attached to it. This is done by using the Principal of the IAM role Arn.

You will still need to ensure that the IAM role contains the permissions it needs to access S3 additionally.

Comment: but adding the policy to the lambda role shouldn't be enough? Why do I need to add Lambda role to the s3 bucket whitelist?

Comment: Its because of the interaction model, the Lambda will always connect to the service by using the IAM role so the S3 API will only ever be aware that the IAM role in question is trying to reach out to it.

Comment: The `aws:SourceArn` would be used by a service that does not use IAM but instead uses its own resource policies such as SNS (which can act as a post trigger for S3).